# Python regular expression find words with part of text

Tags: python, regex

I want to find in text such phrases.(i don't have ideas how to make it)

1. -is- and -to- in phrase which  in big text, or IS and TO

> love-is-beatiful-to-you
>
> love-IS-beatiful-TO-you
>
> loveISbeatifulTOyou

For example

> " The sun is black but love-IS-beatiful-TO-you when you smile"

output

> love-IS-beatiful-TO-you

2. if FORyou text in sentence and I want to get whole sentence

example

> Open your eyes and love. come.fastFORyou immediately

I would like to get(as you can see it can be dots, and spaces)

> love. come.fastFORyou

Comment: *I want to get whole sentence* -  `love. come.fastFORyou` - doesn't look like a single sentence.It looks like a parts of two sentences. It would be more reasonable to get only `come.fastFORyou`, I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following solution using `re.findall()` function with specific regex pattern:

```
import re 

s = " The sun is black but love-IS-beatiful-TO-you when you smile. Open your eyes and love. come.fastFORyou immediately"
result = re.findall(r'(\b\w+-?is-?\w+-?to-?\w+\b|(?:\w+(?:\.|\. )?)+foryou\b)', s, re.I)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['love-IS-beatiful-TO-you', 'love. come.fastFORyou']
```